# Delete text box that says XXXX and replace with new text box with different text for each slide

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

Fairly long code here that I inherited.  This code creates a title text box on each slide that says title = "[XXXXXX]".

I need to change the title for each slide, so for example, slide 1 needs to delete the [XXXXXX] and replace it with "Executive Summary". Slide 2 needs to replace the [XXXXXX] with "Borrower Characteristics". Slide 3 needs to replace "[XXXXXX]" with something else.

How do I adjust this code so that I can adjust the specific language needed for each individual slide?

Thanks!

```
'Create PowerPoint Final
Option Explicit

Dim title As String
    
Sub CopyChartsToPowerPoint()

    '########################
    ' Revised: Desc
    ' 2023_01_22: Add macro
    '########################
    
    '// excel variables/objects
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim source_sheet As Worksheet
    Dim chart_obj As ChartObject
    Dim i As Long, last_row As Long, tracker As Long
    
    '// powerpoint variables/objects
    Dim pp_app As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pp_presentation As Presentation
    Dim pp_slide As Slide
    Dim pp_shape As Object
    Dim pp_slider_tracker As Long, n As Long

    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set source_sheet = wb.Worksheets("portfolio_charts")
    
    Set pp_app = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set pp_presentation = pp_app.Presentations.Add
    
    pp_slider_tracker = 1
    n = 41
    title = "[XXXXXX]"
    
    last_row = source_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
   'Set pp_slide = pp_presentation.Slides.Add(pp_slider_tracker, ppLayoutBlank)
    Set pp_slide = pp_presentation.Slides.Add(pp_slider_tracker, ppLayoutCustom)
    
    For i = 1 To last_row
'        Stop
'        Debug.Assert i < 20
'
'        If i Mod 37 = 5 Or i Mod 37 = 9 Or i Mod 37 = 13 Or i Mod 37 = 17 _
'            Or i Mod 37 = 21 Or (i Mod 37 > 23 And i Mod 37 < 37) Or i Mod 37 = 0 Or (i Mod 37 = 1 And pp_slider_tracker > 1) Then
        If (i Mod n = 1 And pp_slider_tracker > 1) Or i Mod n = 5 Or i Mod n = 7 Or i Mod n = 10 Or i Mod n = 13 Or i Mod n = 16 Or i Mod n = 18 Or i Mod n = 22 Or i Mod n = 24 Or _
            (i Mod n > 27 Or i Mod n = 0) Then
        
            pp_slider_tracker = pp_slider_tracker + 1
            Set pp_slide = pp_presentation.Slides.Add(pp_slider_tracker, ppLayoutBlank)
                    
        End If
        
        Set chart_obj = source_sheet.ChartObjects(source_sheet.Cells(i, "A").Value)
        chart_obj.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
                     
        'Set pp_shape = pp_slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)
        Set pp_shape = pp_slide.Shapes.Paste

        Select Case i Mod n
            
            '// four/three charts
            Case 1, 7, 10, 13, 18, 24
                Call position_chart_top_left(pp_shape)
                Call insert_title(pp_slide)
                Call insert_h_line_1(pp_slide)
                Call insert_h_line_2(pp_slide)
                Call insert_v_line_1(pp_slide)
            
            '// top right
            Case 2, 8, 11, 14, 19, 25
                Call position_chart_top_right(pp_shape)
            
            '// bottom left
            Case 3, 9, 12, 15, 20, 26
                Call position_chart_bottom_left(pp_shape)
            
            '// bottom right
            Case 4, 21, 27
                Call position_chart_bottom_right(pp_shape)
            
            '// two charts
            Case 5, 16, 22
                Call position_chart_top_left(pp_shape)
                Call position_chart_double_chart(pp_shape)
                Call insert_title(pp_slide)
                Call insert_h_line_1(pp_slide)
                Call insert_v_line_1(pp_slide)
                pp_shape.Height = 325
                
            '// two charts
            Case 6, 17, 23
                Call position_chart_top_right(pp_shape)
                Call position_chart_double_chart(pp_shape)
                Call insert_title(pp_slide)
                Call insert_h_line_1(pp_slide)
                Call insert_v_line_1(pp_slide)
                pp_shape.Height = 325
                
            Case 28 To n, 0
                Call position_chart_single_chart(pp_shape)
                Call insert_title(pp_slide)
                Call insert_h_line_1(pp_slide)
                pp_shape.Height = 375
        End Select
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))

    Next i

End Sub



Private Sub position_chart_top_left(ByVal pp_shape As Object)

        pp_shape.Left = 66
        pp_shape.Top = 86

End Sub

Private Sub position_chart_top_right(ByVal pp_shape As Object)

        pp_shape.Left = 510
        pp_shape.Top = 86
                
End Sub

Private Sub position_chart_bottom_left(ByVal pp_shape As Object)

        pp_shape.Left = 66
        pp_shape.Top = 306

End Sub

Private Sub position_chart_bottom_right(ByVal pp_shape As Object)

        pp_shape.Left = 510
        pp_shape.Top = 306

End Sub

Private Sub position_chart_single_chart(ByVal pp_shape As Object)

        pp_shape.Left = 127
        pp_shape.Top = 90
        pp_shape.Width = 706
        pp_shape.Height = 300
            
End Sub

Private Sub position_chart_double_chart(ByVal pp_shape As Object)

        pp_shape.Top = 90
        pp_shape.Height = 300
            
End Sub

Private Sub insert_title(ByVal pp_slide As Slide)

        Dim slide_title As Object
            
        Set slide_title = pp_slide.Shapes.AddTextbox(1, 34.36292, -2.670787, 900, 90)
        With slide_title
            .Height = 54
            .Left = 34.36292
            .Top = 15
            .Width = 190
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = title
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold = True
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
            .TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color = RGB(0, 133, 85)
        End With

End Sub

Private Sub insert_h_line_1(ByVal pp_slide As Slide)

        Dim line1 As Object
        
        Set line1 = pp_slide.Shapes.AddLine(beginx:=10, beginy:=57.6, endx:=924, endy:=57.6).Line
        With line1
            .Weight = 2
            .Parent.Left = 18
            .Parent.Top = 48
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(140, 140, 140)
            
            With .Parent.Shadow
                .Transparency = 0.6
                .Visible = True
                .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
            End With
        End With
            
End Sub

Private Sub insert_h_line_2(ByVal pp_slide As Slide)
            
            Dim line2 As Object
            
            Set line2 = pp_slide.Shapes.AddLine(beginx:=10, beginy:=57.6, endx:=924, endy:=57.6).Line
            With line2
                .Weight = 2
                .Parent.Left = 18
                .Parent.Top = 285
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(140, 140, 140)
                
                With .Parent.Shadow
                    .Transparency = 0.6
                    .Visible = True
                    .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
                End With
            End With
                
End Sub

Private Sub insert_v_line_1(ByVal pp_slide As Slide)
            
            Dim line3 As Object
            
            Set line3 = pp_slide.Shapes.AddLine(beginx:=10, beginy:=10, endx:=924, endy:=10).Line
            With line3
                .Weight = 2
                .Parent.Width = 430
                .Parent.Rotation = 90
                .Parent.Left = 264
                .Parent.Top = 268
                
                .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(140, 140, 140)
                
                With .Parent.Shadow
                    .Transparency = 0.6
                    .Visible = True
                    .Style = msoShadowStyleOuterShadow
                End With
            End With
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass the title to `insert_title`?  You could read the title from your `source_sheet` if you add it there instead of hard-coding it in your VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a sheet named "title", assign it to `wsTitle` and put text in column A. Eg "Executive Summary" in A1,"Borrower" in A2 etc. Then in Sub insert_title() change line

```vb
'.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = title
.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = wsTitle.Cells(pp_slide.SlideIndex,"A")
```

You can put different languages in other columns and change "A" accordingly.